# C# repeating text to speech synthesis

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, speechsynthesizer

So I am trying to write a text to speech program that will progressively get faster, leaving less of a gap between sentences  and eventually over layering and running multiple of the commands at the same time so it becomes just a mess of noise. Its currently a console application and I have the relevant references included

Any ideas how I adapt this to run each speak command as its own instance. Would I have to re-learn how to multithread to get it to work?

Any help would be great, at the minute it loops (the number of iterations is not too important) and I have tried to get less of a pause after each one but cannot get one speak command to layer over the pervious.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        string commandLine2 = "Hello darkness my old friend";
                        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                        s.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Child);
                        s.Speak(commandLine2);
                        commandLine2 = "Its been a while where should we begin";
                        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        s.Speak(commandLine2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string commandLine2 = "Hello darkness my old friend";
                    SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                    s.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Child);
                    s.Speak(commandLine2);
                    commandLine2 = "Its been a while where should we begin";
                    //Thread.Sleep(1000 / i);
                    s.Speak(commandLine2);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: So that overlapping is the goal, or it's the bug you want to fix? How it behaves right now, speaks over equal intervals?

Comment: Are you using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=netframework-4.8  ?

Comment: The over lap is the goal, currently it just speaks after one sentence is finished but want to cause the overlap. yes using that class, wasn't aware of any others

Answer (score 1):

I just used multithreading in the end. It all came rushing back to me

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(mySpeach);
            t1.Name = "Thread1";
            t1.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(2000 / i);
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
            {
                t1.Abort();
                break;
            }
        }

//other methods were here


    public static void typing()
        {
        string a = "Hello darkness my old friend\nIts been a while where should we begin";
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.Write(a[i]);
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(50, 100));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void mySpeach()
    {
        string commandLine2 = "Hello darkness my old friend";
        Thread t2 = new Thread(typing);

        t2.Name = "Thread2";

        t2.Start();
        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        s.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Child);
        s.Speak(commandLine2);
        commandLine2 = "Its been a while where should we begin";
        if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
        {
            return;
        }
        s.Speak(commandLine2);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```